# In Arkham Horror, how many gates wakes the Ancient One?

Tags: arkham-horror

If the max number of gates allowed on the board is, for example, 6, does the Ancient One wake up on the 6th or 7th gate?

I'm pretty sure that the answer to that should be that the Ancient One wakes up on the 7th gate, but I'm not too sure.

Additionally and as a clarification, all gates count regardless of if they are on the expansion boards, right? It's the monsters that don't count if they're outside Arkham itself.

Answer (score 5):

See page 20 of the [rulebook](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/AH_Rules_internat.pdf).  It has a table with the number of players vs. the number of open gates with the note:

> The number of open gates that will **immediately** awaken the
>   Ancient One depends on the number of players.

For 5 players, the number is 6.  When the sixth gate is opened, the Ancient One will awaken immediately.

Gates count towards the total wherever they are.  Do remember that when playing with more than one large expansion board you should count the total number of players as one less than actual for most purposes including the number of open gates needed to awaken the ancient one.

Comment: Additionally, if you purchase the Miskatonic Horror expansion, it comes with reference cards that list the various limits when there are 1-8 investigators with any number of expansion boards.